# SonarLint and "common-java" analyzers

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

Using Sonar 6.7 with SonarLint in InteliJ the rule "Source files should have a sufficient density of comment lines" pops-up during Sonar analysis. But since this is not a Sonar rule ("squid:") but a "common-java" then SonarLint won't report it.
Is there a way to apply such a rule(s) before commit?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. As far as I know these rules are executed on the server-side and their results cannot be displayed with SonarLint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling around SonarQube plugin (https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin) could be used and works perfectly. Connects to Sonar server, performs LOCAL analysis (issues are not created on server) based on server configuration, reports only new issues and its possible to hook this to auto-analysis done before commit.